# Why does a half filled Brillouin zone result in conductivity?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, conductors

As stated in the title, why does a half filled [Brillouin zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone) result in an element being a conductor, or conversely, why does a filled Brillouin zone result in an insulator?

Comment: Do you understand the basis of band gaps? In particular, how they relate to wave vectors?

Comment: Yes I think so. At least, to the extent that it's explained by Kittel in 'Intro to solid state physics'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine the single energy-bands as a set of "places" ($\rightarrow$ states) which can be ingested by an electron for example. Between these sets of places there are gaps (at least for non-free electrongas models).
So if the band is not filled up, electrons can "swap seats" and conductivity is given. If your band is full you need a quite "huge" amount of energy to swap the electron to a free seat which is far away (on the other band), so electrons can barely move.

I hope that fits even though its a rather vivid explanation.